# ActiveAdmin auto create single nested item

Tags: ruby, activeadmin

I have `User`, and every user must have one `Contact` item (but not all contacts need to have a user). A user can create contacts via nested forms, but I'm not happy with that.

How do I set it so that when I go to new `User`, it automatically creates the first one and won't allow me to add more contact items?

Answer (score 0):

After doing some searching I found the answer, and it comes in two steps.

First, to ensure that the first nested item is created first, you need to first override the new method of the controller and initialise all the sub items you want first, this will cause the page to render with the nested items created.

Using my question as the example, you would do it like this:

```
controller do
  def new
    @user = User.new
    @user.contact = Contact.new
    new!
  end
end
```

The second is to add the following to your active_admin css file:

```
#new_user .has_many_remove {
  display: none;
}
```

with `#new_user` being the name of my form, substitute this with the name of your form.

I found the answer [here](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/4415#issuecomment-252777281) on a github issue for ActiveAdmin.